# Quand est-il permis d'utiliser « en » en même temps que « de » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

J'ai entendu des choses comme ceci :

> Je n'en peux plus de ces insomnies.

C'est un peu étrange pour moi, parce que je pensais que le « en » remplacerait le « de ces insomnies » mais ça ne se produit pas dans ce cas-là.

Alors, est-ce possible dire des choses comme ça quand on parle :

> Voulez-vous votre sandwich ?
>
> Non, j'en n'ai pas besoin de mon sandwich.

Ou, est-ce que l'utilisation de « en » et de « de... » est réservée pour les idiomes comme « je n'en peux plus » ?

Answer (score 6):

> Je n'en peux plus de ces insomnies.

Le « en » fait partie de la locution verbale : « n’en pouvoir plus ». Sans le « en » le verbe pouvoir aurait un tout autre sens.

Le « en » ne représente pas « ces insomnies » qui n'est là que pour préciser la raison de l'abattement du locuteur. Il n'est pas pronom personnel, il ne remplace rien du tout. Grevisse dit qu'il a une « valeur imprécise », vaguement pronominale, vaguement adverbiale.

Il existe en français de nombreuses locutions verbales qui nécessitent « en » et qui donnent au verbe un sens différent de celui qu'il a sans ce « en » :
*s'en faire*, *en avoir assez*, *en vouloir (à quelqu'un)*, *s'en prendre (à quelqu'un)*, *en coûter* (*il m'en coûte*), *en revenir* (je n'en reviens pas = je suis étonné), *en rester là*, *s'en tirer*, *il s'en faut de peu*, *ça en est trop*, …

> Voulez-vous votre sandwich? Non, j'en n'ai pas besoin de mon sandwich.

Ici le « en » est effectivement pronom personnel et représente le sandwich. C'est un « en » emphatique, non obligatoire, on pourrait dire :

> je n'ai pas besoin de mon sandwich.

Dans les deux cas l'emploi de « de » n'exclut pas l'emploi de « en ».

Answer (score 2):

Dans les deux exemples donnés, *de* a la même fonction grammaticale: *de* introduit un complément d'objet indirect.

Mais les deux exemples sont assez différents. Le premier:

> Je n'en peux plus de ces insomnies.

utilise une locution française figée: *je n'en peux plus* que l'on peut trouver telle quelle ou suivi d'un COI introduit par *de*.

Dans le deuxième:

> Voulez-vous votre sandwich? Non, j'en n'ai pas besoin de mon sandwich.
>   (dont je corrigerais la réponse en *je n'en ai pas besoin [de mon sandwich].*

*sandwich* est annoncé dans la question et il n'y a pas de possibilité de confondre avec un autre complément (comme ce pourrait être le cas dans une question telle que *voulez-vous votre sandwich et votre boisson*). Donc, dans la réponse, *en* reprend clairement *sandwich*. Il n'est donc plus nécessaire de préciser *de mon sandwich*.