# What does "en" refer to in "J'en ris encore"?

Tags: grammaire

Quote:

> — Mais qu'est-ce qui se passe Rylan ? pourquoi tu souris comme ça ?
>   D'habitude, quand on parle de grammaire, tu n'as pas envie de rire.
>
> — J'étais en train de repenser à la pièce de théâtre que je suis allé voir hier soir. C'était génial ! **J'en ris encore.** Et toi, Julie ?

Well, I know that the pronoun **en** usually refers to a previously mentioned noun or noun phrase that's preceded by the preposition **de**. In this case, what is he still laughing about? Logically speaking, it follows that he would be laughing about the play that he saw in the theatre last night. But since it's the whole phrase **repenser à la pièce de théâtre que...** that's preceded by **de**, it must be the case that he is still laughing about the process of rethinking the play that he saw last night because, according to grammar, **repenser à la pièce de théâtre que...** should be the antecedent of the **en**? Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right about the use of *en* when it is a personal pronoun.

> ***en*** usually refers to a previously mentioned noun or noun phrase that's preceded by the preposition ***de***.

The difficulty in the present case is that there are two ***de*** one is expressed, the other is not.

*En train de* is a phrase that must be followed by a verb and that is **not** the one we should be looking at.

We also have *rire **de*** (followed by a noun phrase) and that is the one to consider. But ***de*** is not explicit here, which is why you missed it although your initial understanding of the sentence was correct.

You can see the sentence as:

- Je ris encore de la pièce/ de la soirée d'hier. → J'en ris encore.

But since the whole context (the evening, the play...) has just been mentioned there is no need to repeat it, we express it with *en*.

Comment: So, how would you then translate your example: **Je ris encore de la pièce. J'en ris encore**? Like this: **I'm still laughing about the play. I'm still laughing about it?**

Comment: @user69786 Yes, I'm still laughing about it. Note that **en** can be other things than a personal pronoun. There are already seevral posts about this, e.g. [this one](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8778/quand-est-il-permis-dutiliser-en-en-m%c3%aame-temps-que-de/8785#8785)

Comment: Could you please do me a favor? I'd like you to transcribe this short audio clip for me: https://clyp.it/iqkzuqn2 It's really just a few seconds long. There are two words that I don't understand in that audio clip. The word at the very beginning and the word at the very end.

Comment: @user69786 I left you a message [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette), it's more appropriate for this kind of requests.

Answer (score -3):

It refers to “still” as I am still laughing at it (knowing the event happened in the past and is other)

Hope it helps
LT

Comment: Still is *encore*, nothing to do with *en*.

Comment: I appreciate your point of view. Then following your logic it should be “at” in my sentence. Which mean, the juxtaposition of “still + at” is the correct translation of “en+encore”

Comment: I was referring to this part of you answer: "It refers to “still”" supposing  that *it* in your sentence represented *en* (you were answering the question "What does “en” refer to in “J'en ris encore”?).  *en* does not refer to "still".  "Still" is an adverb and in the OP's sentence it means *encore*.

Comment: Thanks Laure for this clarification- as the aim of SoF is to help the end user, I am sure we can agree my latest refinement is then correctly answering to the question isn’t it.

Comment: I'm afraid not, the OP was asking about *en* and you are saying that *en* refers to *still*, which is not correct.